# pandas dataframe calculation based on condition only for specific cells

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe with me.

```
amount entry/exit
  1000       exit
  1100      entry
  1140      entry
  1200      entry
  1500       exit
  1400       exit
  1200      entry
  1100      entry
  1000       exit
  1100       exit
  1500      entry
```

I want to have a calculation against first entry as next exit-entry. it should look like this

```
amount entry/exit difference
  1000       exit     ignore
  1100      entry        400
  1140      entry     ignore
  1200      entry     ignore
  1500       exit     ignore
  1400       exit     ignore
  1200      entry       -200
  1100      entry     ignore
  1000       exit     ignore
  1100       exit     ignore
  1500      entry     ignore
```

I have 2000 files of this and calculation should be against first entry and on first exit in between entry to be ignored and next calculation to be done on next first entry after the exit

Comment: Please show the logic of `difference` column. It would be better to get help if your test data is in well-organized format (ie. Markdown table).

Comment: sorry i dint know about markdown table. logic of the difference column is to calculate diff of amount on first entry to first exit. after that again calculate on first entry after the exit.

Comment: so the diff is of 1500 - 1100=400. then again look for next entry calculate 1000-1200=-200

Comment: edited my question for clarity

Comment: thank you so much @taller_ExcelHome it worked like a magic spell..thank you so much for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option1: Loop through the DataFrame rows and calculate the differences.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'amount': [1000, 1100, 1140, 1200, 1500, 1400, 
                   1200, 1100, 1000, 1100, 1500],
        'entry/exit': ['exit', 'entry', 'entry', 'entry', 'exit', 'exit', 
                       'entry', 'entry', 'exit', 'exit', 'entry']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print("="*20)

df['difference'] = 'ignore'
entry_row = None
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['entry/exit'] == 'entry' and entry_row is None:
            entry_row = i
    elif row['entry/exit'] == 'exit' and entry_row is not None:
        # Calculate difference 
        df.at[entry_row, 'difference'] = row['amount'] - df.at[entry_row, 'amount']
        entry_row = None
print(df)
```

---

Option 2: It is more efficient than loop through all rows in DF.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
data = {'amount': [1000, 1100, 1140, 1200, 1500, 1400, 
                   1200, 1100, 1000, 1100, 1500],
        'entry/exit': ['exit', 'entry', 'entry', 'entry', 'exit', 'exit', 
                       'entry', 'entry', 'exit', 'exit', 'entry']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print("="*20)
# Get entry and exit index
entry_indices = df[df['entry/exit'] == 'entry'].index
exit_indices = df[df['entry/exit'] == 'exit'].index
start_idx = -1
df['difference'] = 'ignore'
for entry_idx in entry_indices:
    if entry_idx > start_idx:
        # Get the next exit index
        next_exit_idx = exit_indices[exit_indices > entry_idx].min()
        if pd.notnull(next_exit_idx):
            # Update the difference
            df.loc[entry_idx, 'difference'] = (df.loc[next_exit_idx, 'amount']
                                                 - df.loc[entry_idx, 'amount'])
            start_idx = next_exit_idx
print(df)
```

```
**Output**
    amount entry/exit
0     1000       exit
1     1100      entry
2     1140      entry
3     1200      entry
4     1500       exit
5     1400       exit
6     1200      entry
7     1100      entry
8     1000       exit
9     1100       exit
10    1500      entry
====================
    amount entry/exit difference
0     1000       exit     ignore
1     1100      entry        400
2     1140      entry     ignore
3     1200      entry     ignore
4     1500       exit     ignore
5     1400       exit     ignore
6     1200      entry       -200
7     1100      entry     ignore
8     1000       exit     ignore
9     1100       exit     ignore
10    1500      entry     ignore
```

Comment: You can simplify: `if row['entry/exit'] == 'entry' and entry_row is None: entry_row = i`